# how to open .cns file in cytoscape

Tags: r, import, cytoscape

I have used this command in R using Linkcomm package and generate this temp.cns file

```
linkcomm2clustnsee(lc, file = "temp.cns", network.name = "network")
```

I am trying to import temp.cns file into cytoscape for visualizing cluster.but i am unable to import this. can anyone tell how to import this type of file. I am using window 8 , cytoscape version 2.8 and plugin clustnsee to visualize clusters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

download clustnsee library from cytoscape app store and visualize this file using cytoscape